# The Hausdorff measure of intersection of annulus and conformal curve

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Recently I came across a problem in my research. Let $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ be a restriction of a conformal map that is defined in a simply connected domain $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ that include $[0,1]\times\{0\}$. Let $\Gamma:=g([0,1])$. **I believe that  the following statement is true and want to prove it**: there exists $C>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that for any $z\in\Gamma$, $r>0$ and $\rho>0$, we have
$$\mathcal{H}^1(\Gamma\cap(B(z,r+\rho)\backslash B(z,r-\rho)))\leq C\rho^{\delta},$$
where $\mathcal{H}^1$ denote the one-dimensional Hausdorff measure.  What I have already known is the fact that there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\#(\Gamma\cap \partial B(z,r))\leq N$ for any $z\in\Gamma$ and $r>0$. This fact can be proved by identity theorem from basic complex analysis and a compactness argument. Using this fact, I believe that $\Gamma\cap (B(z,r+\rho)\backslash B(z,r-\rho))$ is just a union of at most $N$ intervals in the curve $\Gamma$ whenever $z\in\Gamma$, $r>0$ and $\rho$ is sufficiently small. So if we want to know the $\mathcal{H}^1$-measure of the intersection, the key point may be to estimate the length of these intervals. But I don't know how to do this.

Can anyone give me some advice? Thank you very much!